# Split a Tuple of ranges to a set of inner and outer loops

Tags: julia

Consider a `Tuple` length `N` of `UnitRange` (or really any range), for clarity let's call it `interestingranges`.
The motivation is to iterate over the range in a specific dimension `idir` (`interestingranges[idir]`) as the most inner loop and the ranges in the remaining directions by order (the fastest) as outer loop(s).

The idea I had was to generate a function `f` which leaves the range in `idir` as is and "splats" all the other dimensions, creating set that can be used as `CartesianIndices` for an outer loop and have the inner loop based on the remaining range.
Here is what an example for `N=3`: `interestingranges = (1:6, 1:5, 1:3)` such that the function `f` needs to produce the following results:

```
f(interestingranges,1) produces the set `(1:6, 1, 1), (1:6, 2, 1), ... , (1:6, 5, 3)
f(interestingranges,2) produces the set `(1, 1:5, 1), (2, 1:5, 1), ... , (6, 1:5, 3)
f(interestingranges,3) produces the set `(1, 1, 1:3), (2, 1, 1:3), ... , (6, 5, 1:3)
```

I'm certain there are smarter and more efficient ideas, and I'm more than happy to read those!
But for my curiosity and education, I'd like to know (also) how to generate `f` as described.

Comment: @Mark And you would be perfectly correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A one-liner:

```
f(t, n) = Iterators.product(t[1:n-1]..., [t[n]], t[n+1:end]...)
```

```
julia> collect(f(interestingranges, 2))
6×1×3 Array{Tuple{Int64, UnitRange{Int64}, Int64}, 3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 (1, 1:5, 1)
 (2, 1:5, 1)
 (3, 1:5, 1)
 (4, 1:5, 1)
 (5, 1:5, 1)
 (6, 1:5, 1)

[:, :, 2] =
 (1, 1:5, 2)
 (2, 1:5, 2)
 (3, 1:5, 2)
 (4, 1:5, 2)
 (5, 1:5, 2)
 (6, 1:5, 2)

[:, :, 3] =
 (1, 1:5, 3)
 (2, 1:5, 3)
 (3, 1:5, 3)
 (4, 1:5, 3)
 (5, 1:5, 3)
 (6, 1:5, 3)
```

If you're sure the number of combinations you're going to create isn't going to be ridiculously huge, you can move the `collect()` inside of the function. But if not, keep it on the outside, and iterate using the [iterator](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/iterators/#Base.Iterators.product).

Comment: Oh hi Mark! I was not aware this is the functionality of Iterators.product. Thank you.

Comment: Nice! Didn’t know that was possible.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I can follow your line of thought, but looking at the example a function `f` could look like this:

```
function f(ranges, i)
    # list of indexes of all ranges except for range i
    range_idxs = [x for x in 1:length(ranges) if x != i]
    # Cartesian product of input ranges (except range i)
    combinations = collect(Base.product(ranges[range_idxs]...))
    # iterate over all elements in combinations-matrix and store prepared elements in result_set
    result_set = Set()
    for idx in eachindex(combinations)
        # convert combination (tuple) at index idx to an (mutable) array of type Any so that range i can easily inserted
        element = collect(Any, combinations[idx]) 
        # insert interestingranges[i] at index i and convert to tuple again
        element_with_range = (insert!(element, i, ranges[i])...,)
        # add element wíth range to result set
        push!(result_set, element_with_range)
    end
    return result_set
end
```

Although the order of elements in the result set can of course be different from the example, since it is an (unordered) set.

The loop could also be written as a (somewhat unreadable) one-liner.

```
result_set  = Set((insert!(collect(Any, combinations[idx]), i, interestingranges[i])...,) for idx in eachindex(combinations))
```

Comment: Though this should work, I am also happy to hear if there are better (more efficient?) solutions...

Comment: rosa check my answer! :-) I managed to get it down to one line